# In RabbitMQ, how to get all error messages from all _error queues

Tags: rabbitmq

I've been ask to get a list of all the exceptions in all of our RabbitMQ _error queues.

[image]

I can use the admin site to copy and paste from every _error queue.

1. But is there a way from the command line to get such a list.
2. Or maybe I can get a Json backup of the rabbitmq database and analysis that file?

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to attach a consumer and get all the messages.
There, you can add all the filters you want.

You can add a new queue with all the messages in copy to avoid touching the main queue.

So you will have something like:

your_exchange bounds to two queues:

- your_error_queue
- your_copy_error_queue

Another solution is to use the [stream queue](https://www.rabbitmq.com/docs/streams), where you can analyse and filter your data all the time you want.